# SEO Friendly con GeneXus (Java)

Tags: genexus, seo

Necesito cambiar el formato de la url de un WebPanel, por ejemplo pasar de:
`http://sitio.com/webpanel?memoria,kingston`

a:

`http://sitio.com/productos/kingston/memoria`

La idea es hacerlo SEO friendly. Lo logré con el módulo Tuckey de redireccionamiento del Tomcat, y también probé con el mod_rewrite usando al Apache como proxy, pero el gran problema es que una vez en la página, GeneXus arma los links usando como url base la nueva url, que es ficticia.

Por ejemplo, parados en `http://sitio.com/productos/kingston/memoria` al hacer click en un botón que tiene que llevar al inicio, en vez de ir a  `http://sitio.com/inicio` va a `http://sitio.com/productos/kingston/inicio`

Answer (score 1):

Cuando utilizas URL rewriting con GeneXus, debes no sólo encargarte de resolver el rewriting en el servidor (eso ya lo tendrías resuelto), si no que también debes modificar la forma en que llamas de un objeto a otro en el código de tus objetos, para que los links que se arman, sean coherentes con el rewriting.

Si antes tenías lo siguiente:

```
TextBlock.Link = Inicio.Link()
```

Deberías pasar a tener lo siguiente:

```
TextBlock.Link = LinkRewrite(Inicio.Link())
```

Donde el procedimiento `LinkRewrite` debe hacerse cargo de ajustar el link retornado por `Inicio.Link()` para que sea coherente con el rewriting que estas haciendo.

En general, `LinkRewrite` va a hacer lo inverso a lo que tienes configurado en el módulo de URL rewriting. Es decir, si en el módulo de rewriting haces la siguiente transformación:

```
/productos/kingston/memoria -> productos?kingston,memoria
```

El procedimiento LinkRewrite debería ser invocado de la siguiente manera:

```
TextBlock.Link = LinkRewrite(Productos.Link("kingston", "memoria"))
```

para que produzca la siguiente transformación:

```
productos?kingston,memoria -> /productos/kingston/memoria
```

Dentro de `LinkRewrite` deberías separar la URL recibida por parámetro en partes, y reescribirla para que tenga el formato deseado.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas Gracias por la aclaración.

El problema que no podía resolver y omití mencionar es al abrir un popup.

-Si instanciaba el objeto con la función "create", usando variable &window, lo abre como http://sitio.com/productos/kingston/memoria/webpanelPopUp

-Si lo hacía con la función PopUp, también lo abre como http://sitio.com/productos/kingston/memoria/webpanelPopUp

-También probé de crear una nueva regla de ReWrite para que transforme la url al  formato y folder original, pero provoca un resultado extraño: Se abre el popup, pero incluyendo la masterpage en el popup, cuando no debería.

Finalmente la solución fué:

**-Asignar la url traducida correctamente a la propiedad "url" de la variable &window.**

(el problema era que antes había probado esta última solución sin éxito, porque en vez de cerrar el popup volvía al llamador en el mismo popup, pero era un error de programación de que no se estaba ejecutando el return como lo previsto, y estaba "entrando" por otro lado).

Muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Hola Adrian, veo que eres el mismo user de la pregunta. Has de pulsar en [Contacto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact) y ahi seleccionar "Necesito combinar perfiles de usuario" para juntarlos ambos. Así la pregunta y la respuesta perteneran a la misma cuenta . Un saludo